# find object in in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, recursion

Hi want to search in this array of objects. This Objects can have childrean with array of objects. These is really difficult to find a logic to find a object. I tried it with.

```
 let obj =  DATA.children.find(o => o.size === 4461)
```

This looks only in the first layer. I want to look in the whole object.
Have somebody an idea? Maybe there is an easy solution? 
Example Object:

```
let DATA = {
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [{
        "name": "analytics",
        "children": [{
            "name": "cluster",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                "size": 3938
            }, {
                "name": "CommunityStructure",           
                "size": 3812
            }, {
                "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                "size": 6714
            }, {
                "name": "MergeEdge",
                "size": 743
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "graph",
            "children": [{
                "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
                "size": 3534
            }, {
                "name": "LinkDistance",
                "size": 5731
            }, {
                "name": "MaxFlowMinCut",
                "size": 7840
            }, {
                "name": "ShortestPaths",
                "size": 5914
            }, {
                "name": "SpanningTree",
                "size": 3416
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "optimization",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
                "size": 7074
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "animate",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Easing",
            "size": 17010
        }, {
            "name": "FunctionSequence",
            "size": 5842
        }, {
            "name": "interpolate",
            "children": [{
                "name": "ArrayInterpolator",
                "size": 1983
            }, {
                "name": "ColorInterpolator",
                "size": 2047
            }, {
                "name": "DateInterpolator",
                "size": 1375
            }, {
                "name": "Interpolator",
                "size": 8746
            }, {
                "name": "MatrixInterpolator",
                "size": 2202
            }, {
                "name": "NumberInterpolator",
                "size": 1382
            }, {
                "name": "ObjectInterpolator",
                "size": 1629
            }, {
                "name": "PointInterpolator",
                "size": 1675
            }, {
                "name": "RectangleInterpolator",
                "size": 2042
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "ISchedulable",
            "size": 1041
        }, {
            "name": "Parallel",
            "size": 5176
        }, {
            "name": "Pause",
            "size": 449
        }, {
            "name": "Scheduler",
            "size": 5593
        }, {
            "name": "Sequence",
            "size": 5534
        }, {
            "name": "Transition",
            "size": 9201
        }, {
            "name": "Transitioner",
            "size": 19975
        }, {
            "name": "TransitionEvent",
            "size": 1116
        }, {
            "name": "Tween",
            "size": 6006
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "data",
        "children": [{
            "name": "converters",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Converters",
                "size": 721
            }, {
                "name": "DelimitedTextConverter",
                "size": 4294
            }, {
                "name": "GraphMLConverter",
                "size": 9800
            }, {
                "name": "IDataConverter",
                "size": 1314
            }, {
                "name": "JSONConverter",
                "size": 2220
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "DataField",
            "size": 1759
        }, {
            "name": "DataSchema",
            "size": 2165
        }, {
            "name": "DataSet",
            "size": 586
        }, {
            "name": "DataSource",
            "size": 3331
        }, {
            "name": "DataTable",
            "size": 772
        }, {
            "name": "DataUtil",
            "size": 3322
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "display",
        "children": [{
            "name": "DirtySprite",
            "size": 8833
        }, {
            "name": "LineSprite",
            "size": 1732
        }, {
            "name": "RectSprite",
            "size": 3623
        }, {
            "name": "TextSprite",
            "size": 10066
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "flex",
        "children": [{
            "name": "FlareVis",
            "size": 4116
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "physics",
        "children": [{
            "name": "DragForce",
            "size": 1082
        }, {
            "name": "GravityForce",
            "size": 1336
        }, {
            "name": "IForce",
            "size": 319
        }, {
            "name": "NBodyForce",
            "size": 10498
        }, {
            "name": "Particle",
            "size": 2822
        }, {
            "name": "Simulation",
            "size": 9983
        }, {
            "name": "Spring",
            "size": 2213
        }, {
            "name": "SpringForce",
            "size": 1681
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "query",
        "children": [{
            "name": "AggregateExpression",
            "size": 1616
        }, {
            "name": "And",
            "size": 1027
        }, {
            "name": "Arithmetic",
            "size": 3891
        }, {
            "name": "Average",
            "size": 891
        }, {
            "name": "BinaryExpression",
            "size": 2893
        }, {
            "name": "Comparison",
            "size": 5103
        }, {
            "name": "CompositeExpression",
            "size": 3677
        }, {
            "name": "Count",
            "size": 781
        }, {
            "name": "DateUtil",
            "size": 4141
        }, {
            "name": "Distinct",
            "size": 933
        }, {
            "name": "Expression",
            "size": 5130
        }, {
            "name": "ExpressionIterator",
            "size": 3617
        }, {
            "name": "Fn",
            "size": 3240
        }, {
            "name": "If",
            "size": 2732
        }, {
            "name": "IsA",
            "size": 2039
        }, {
            "name": "Literal",
            "size": 1214
        }, {
            "name": "Match",
            "size": 3748
        }, {
            "name": "Maximum",
            "size": 843
        }, {
            "name": "methods",
            "children": [{
                "name": "add",
                "size": 593
            }, {
                "name": "and",
                "size": 330
            }, {
                "name": "average",
                "size": 287
            }, {
                "name": "count",
                "size": 277
            }, {
                "name": "distinct",
                "size": 292
            }, {
                "name": "div",
                "size": 595
            }, {
                "name": "eq",
                "size": 594
            }, {
                "name": "fn",
                "size": 460
            }, {
                "name": "gt",
                "size": 603
            }, {
                "name": "gte",
                "size": 625
            }, {
                "name": "iff",
                "size": 748
            }, {
                "name": "isa",
                "size": 461
            }, {
                "name": "lt",
                "size": 597
            }, {
                "name": "lte",
                "size": 619
            }, {
                "name": "max",
                "size": 283
            }, {
                "name": "min",
                "size": 283
            }, {
                "name": "mod",
                "size": 591
            }, {
                "name": "mul",
                "size": 603
            }, {
                "name": "neq",
                "size": 599
            }, {
                "name": "not",
                "size": 386
            }, {
                "name": "or",
                "size": 323
            }, {
                "name": "orderby",
                "size": 307
            }, {
                "name": "range",
                "size": 772
            }, {
                "name": "select",
                "size": 296
            }, {
                "name": "stddev",
                "size": 363
            }, {
                "name": "sub",
                "size": 600
            }, {
                "name": "sum",
                "size": 280
            }, {
                "name": "update",
                "size": 307
            }, {
                "name": "variance",
                "size": 335
            }, {
                "name": "where",
                "size": 299
            }, {
                "name": "xor",
                "size": 354
            }, {
                "name": "_",
                "size": 264
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Minimum",
            "size": 843
        }, {
            "name": "Not",
            "size": 1554
        }, {
            "name": "Or",
            "size": 970
        }, {
            "name": "Query",
            "size": 13896
        }, {
            "name": "Range",
            "size": 1594
        }, {
            "name": "StringUtil",
            "size": 4130
        }, {
            "name": "Sum",
            "size": 791
        }, {
            "name": "Variable",
            "size": 1124
        }, {
            "name": "Variance",
            "size": 1876
        }, {
            "name": "Xor",
            "size": 1101
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "scale",
        "children": [{
            "name": "IScaleMap",
            "size": 2105
        }, {
            "name": "LinearScale",
            "size": 1316
        }, {
            "name": "LogScale",
            "size": 3151
        }, {
            "name": "OrdinalScale",
            "size": 3770
        }, {
            "name": "QuantileScale",
            "size": 2435
        }, {
            "name": "QuantitativeScale",
            "size": 4839
        }, {
            "name": "dataScale",
            "size": 1756
        }, {
            "name": "Scale",
            "size": 4268
        }, {
            "name": "ScaleType",
            "size": 1821
        }, {
            "name": "TimeScale",
            "size": 5833
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "util",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Arrays",
            "size": 8258
        }, {
            "name": "Colors",
            "size": 10001
        }, {
            "name": "Dates",
            "size": 8217
        }, {
            "name": "Displays",
            "size": 12555
        }, {
            "name": "Filter",
            "size": 2324
        }, {
            "name": "Geometry",
            "size": 10993
        }, {
            "name": "heap",
            "children": [{
                "name": "FibonacciHeap",
                "size": 9354
            }, {
                "name": "HeapNode",
                "size": 1233
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "IEvaluable",
            "size": 335
        }, {
            "name": "IPredicate",
            "size": 383
        }, {
            "name": "IValueProxy",
            "size": 874
        }, {
            "name": "math",
            "children": [{
                "name": "DenseMatrix",
                "size": 3165
            }, {
                "name": "IMatrix",
                "size": 2815
            }, {
                "name": "SparseMatrix",
                "size": 3366
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Maths",
            "size": 17705
        }, {
            "name": "Orientation",
            "size": 1486
        }, {
            "name": "palette",
            "children": [{
                "name": "ColorPalette",
                "size": 6367
            }, {
                "name": "Palette",
                "size": 1229
            }, {
                "name": "ShapePalette",
                "size": 2059
            }, {
                "name": "SizePalette",
                "size": 2291
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Property",
            "size": 5559
        }, {
            "name": "Shapes",
            "size": 19118
        }, {
            "name": "Sort",
            "size": 6887
        }, {
            "name": "Stats",
            "size": 6557
        }, {
            "name": "Strings",
            "size": 22026
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "vis",
        "children": [{
            "name": "axis",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Axes",
                "size": 1302
            }, {
                "name": "Axis",
                "size": 24593
            }, {
                "name": "AxisGridLine",
                "size": 652
            }, {
                "name": "AxisLabel",
                "size": 636
            }, {
                "name": "CartesianAxes",
                "size": 6703
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "controls",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AnchorControl",
                "size": 2138
            }, {
                "name": "ClickControl",
                "size": 3824
            }, {
                "name": "Control",
                "size": 1353
            }, {
                "name": "ControlList",
                "size": 4665
            }, {
                "name": "DragControl",
                "size": 2649
            }, {
                "name": "ExpandControl",
                "size": 2832
            }, {
                "name": "HoverControl",
                "size": 4896
            }, {
                "name": "IControl",
                "size": 763
            }, {
                "name": "PanZoomControl",
                "size": 5222
            }, {
                "name": "SelectionControl",
                "size": 7862
            }, {
                "name": "TooltipControl",
                "size": 8435
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "data",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Data",
                "size": 20544
            }, {
                "name": "DataList",
                "size": 19788
            }, {
                "name": "DataSprite",
                "size": 10349
            }, {
                "name": "EdgeSprite",
                "size": 3301
            }, {
                "name": "NodeSprite",
                "size": 19382
            }, {
                "name": "render",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "ArrowType",
                    "size": 698
                }, {
                    "name": "EdgeRenderer",
                    "size": 5569
                }, {
                    "name": "IRenderer",
                    "size": 353
                }, {
                    "name": "ShapeRenderer",
                    "size": 2247
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "ScaleBinding",
                "size": 11275
            }, {
                "name": "Tree",
                "size": 7147
            }, {
                "name": "TreeBuilder",
                "size": 9930
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "events",
            "children": [{
                "name": "DataEvent",
                "size": 2313
            }, {
                "name": "SelectionEvent",
                "size": 1880
            }, {
                "name": "TooltipEvent",
                "size": 1701
            }, {
                "name": "VisualizationEvent",
                "size": 1117
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "legend",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Legend",
                "size": 20859
            }, {
                "name": "LegendItem",
                "size": 4614
            }, {
                "name": "LegendRange",
                "size": 10530
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "operator",
            "children": [{
                "name": "distortion",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "BifocalDistortion",
                    "size": 4461
                }, {
                    "name": "Distortion",
                    "size": 6314
                }, {
                    "name": "FisheyeDistortion",
                    "size": 3444
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "encoder",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "ColorEncoder",
                    "size": 3179
                }, {
                    "name": "Encoder",
                    "size": 4060
                }, {
                    "name": "PropertyEncoder",
                    "size": 4138
                }, {
                    "name": "ShapeEncoder",
                    "size": 1690
                }, {
                    "name": "SizeEncoder",
                    "size": 1830
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "filter",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "FisheyeTreeFilter",
                    "size": 5219
                }, {
                    "name": "GraphDistanceFilter",
                    "size": 3165
                }, {
                    "name": "VisibilityFilter",
                    "size": 3509
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "IOperator",
                "size": 1286
            }, {
                "name": "label",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Labeler",
                    "size": 9956
                }, {
                    "name": "RadialLabeler",
                    "size": 3899
                }, {
                    "name": "StackedAreaLabeler",
                    "size": 3202
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "layout",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "AxisLayout",
                    "size": 6725
                }, {
                    "name": "BundledEdgeRouter",
                    "size": 3727
                }, {
                    "name": "CircleLayout",
                    "size": 9317
                }, {
                    "name": "CirclePackingLayout",
                    "size": 12003
                }, {
                    "name": "DendrogramLayout",
                    "size": 4853
                }, {
                    "name": "ForceDirectedLayout",
                    "size": 8411
                }, {
                    "name": "IcicleTreeLayout",
                    "size": 4864
                }, {
                    "name": "IndentedTreeLayout",
                    "size": 3174
                }, {
                    "name": "Layout",
                    "size": 7881
                }, {
                    "name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout",
                    "size": 12870
                }, {
                    "name": "PieLayout",
                    "size": 2728
                }, {
                    "name": "RadialTreeLayout",
                    "size": 12348
                }, {
                    "name": "RandomLayout",
                    "size": 870
                }, {
                    "name": "StackedAreaLayout",
                    "size": 9121
                }, {
                    "name": "TreeMapLayout",
                    "size": 9191
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Operator",
                "size": 2490
            }, {
                "name": "OperatorList",
                "size": 5248
            }, {
                "name": "OperatorSequence",
                "size": 4190
            }, {
                "name": "OperatorSwitch",
                "size": 2581
            }, {
                "name": "SortOperator",
                "size": 2023
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Visualization",
            "size": 16540
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Whenever you see structures like this, you want to look into using recursion.

Comment: Go to your previously asked question [Count Objects in array big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112039/count-objects-in-array-big-data) and use the answer that you didn't mark as the correct answer. I believe you will want to do your check on `child.size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let DATA = {
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [{
        "name": "analytics",
        "children": [{
            "name": "cluster",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                "size": 3938
            }, {
                "name": "CommunityStructure",           
                "size": 3812
            }, {
                "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
                "size": 6714
            }, {
                "name": "MergeEdge",
                "size": 743
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "graph",
            "children": [{
                "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
                "size": 3534
            }, {
                "name": "LinkDistance",
                "size": 5731
            }, {
                "name": "MaxFlowMinCut",
                "size": 7840
            }, {
                "name": "ShortestPaths",
                "size": 5914
            }, {
                "name": "SpanningTree",
                "size": 3416
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "optimization",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
                "size": 7074
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "animate",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Easing",
            "size": 17010
        }, {
            "name": "FunctionSequence",
            "size": 5842
        }, {
            "name": "interpolate",
            "children": [{
                "name": "ArrayInterpolator",
                "size": 1983
            }, {
                "name": "ColorInterpolator",
                "size": 2047
            }, {
                "name": "DateInterpolator",
                "size": 1375
            }, {
                "name": "Interpolator",
                "size": 8746
            }, {
                "name": "MatrixInterpolator",
                "size": 2202
            }, {
                "name": "NumberInterpolator",
                "size": 1382
            }, {
                "name": "ObjectInterpolator",
                "size": 1629
            }, {
                "name": "PointInterpolator",
                "size": 1675
            }, {
                "name": "RectangleInterpolator",
                "size": 2042
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "ISchedulable",
            "size": 1041
        }, {
            "name": "Parallel",
            "size": 5176
        }, {
            "name": "Pause",
            "size": 449
        }, {
            "name": "Scheduler",
            "size": 5593
        }, {
            "name": "Sequence",
            "size": 5534
        }, {
            "name": "Transition",
            "size": 9201
        }, {
            "name": "Transitioner",
            "size": 19975
        }, {
            "name": "TransitionEvent",
            "size": 1116
        }, {
            "name": "Tween",
            "size": 6006
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "data",
        "children": [{
            "name": "converters",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Converters",
                "size": 721
            }, {
                "name": "DelimitedTextConverter",
                "size": 4294
            }, {
                "name": "GraphMLConverter",
                "size": 9800
            }, {
                "name": "IDataConverter",
                "size": 1314
            }, {
                "name": "JSONConverter",
                "size": 2220
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "DataField",
            "size": 1759
        }, {
            "name": "DataSchema",
            "size": 2165
        }, {
            "name": "DataSet",
            "size": 586
        }, {
            "name": "DataSource",
            "size": 3331
        }, {
            "name": "DataTable",
            "size": 772
        }, {
            "name": "DataUtil",
            "size": 3322
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "display",
        "children": [{
            "name": "DirtySprite",
            "size": 8833
        }, {
            "name": "LineSprite",
            "size": 1732
        }, {
            "name": "RectSprite",
            "size": 3623
        }, {
            "name": "TextSprite",
            "size": 10066
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "flex",
        "children": [{
            "name": "FlareVis",
            "size": 4116
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "physics",
        "children": [{
            "name": "DragForce",
            "size": 1082
        }, {
            "name": "GravityForce",
            "size": 1336
        }, {
            "name": "IForce",
            "size": 319
        }, {
            "name": "NBodyForce",
            "size": 10498
        }, {
            "name": "Particle",
            "size": 2822
        }, {
            "name": "Simulation",
            "size": 9983
        }, {
            "name": "Spring",
            "size": 2213
        }, {
            "name": "SpringForce",
            "size": 1681
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "query",
        "children": [{
            "name": "AggregateExpression",
            "size": 1616
        }, {
            "name": "And",
            "size": 1027
        }, {
            "name": "Arithmetic",
            "size": 3891
        }, {
            "name": "Average",
            "size": 891
        }, {
            "name": "BinaryExpression",
            "size": 2893
        }, {
            "name": "Comparison",
            "size": 5103
        }, {
            "name": "CompositeExpression",
            "size": 3677
        }, {
            "name": "Count",
            "size": 781
        }, {
            "name": "DateUtil",
            "size": 4141
        }, {
            "name": "Distinct",
            "size": 933
        }, {
            "name": "Expression",
            "size": 5130
        }, {
            "name": "ExpressionIterator",
            "size": 3617
        }, {
            "name": "Fn",
            "size": 3240
        }, {
            "name": "If",
            "size": 2732
        }, {
            "name": "IsA",
            "size": 2039
        }, {
            "name": "Literal",
            "size": 1214
        }, {
            "name": "Match",
            "size": 3748
        }, {
            "name": "Maximum",
            "size": 843
        }, {
            "name": "methods",
            "children": [{
                "name": "add",
                "size": 593
            }, {
                "name": "and",
                "size": 330
            }, {
                "name": "average",
                "size": 287
            }, {
                "name": "count",
                "size": 277
            }, {
                "name": "distinct",
                "size": 292
            }, {
                "name": "div",
                "size": 595
            }, {
                "name": "eq",
                "size": 594
            }, {
                "name": "fn",
                "size": 460
            }, {
                "name": "gt",
                "size": 603
            }, {
                "name": "gte",
                "size": 625
            }, {
                "name": "iff",
                "size": 748
            }, {
                "name": "isa",
                "size": 461
            }, {
                "name": "lt",
                "size": 597
            }, {
                "name": "lte",
                "size": 619
            }, {
                "name": "max",
                "size": 283
            }, {
                "name": "min",
                "size": 283
            }, {
                "name": "mod",
                "size": 591
            }, {
                "name": "mul",
                "size": 603
            }, {
                "name": "neq",
                "size": 599
            }, {
                "name": "not",
                "size": 386
            }, {
                "name": "or",
                "size": 323
            }, {
                "name": "orderby",
                "size": 307
            }, {
                "name": "range",
                "size": 772
            }, {
                "name": "select",
                "size": 296
            }, {
                "name": "stddev",
                "size": 363
            }, {
                "name": "sub",
                "size": 600
            }, {
                "name": "sum",
                "size": 280
            }, {
                "name": "update",
                "size": 307
            }, {
                "name": "variance",
                "size": 335
            }, {
                "name": "where",
                "size": 299
            }, {
                "name": "xor",
                "size": 354
            }, {
                "name": "_",
                "size": 264
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Minimum",
            "size": 843
        }, {
            "name": "Not",
            "size": 1554
        }, {
            "name": "Or",
            "size": 970
        }, {
            "name": "Query",
            "size": 13896
        }, {
            "name": "Range",
            "size": 1594
        }, {
            "name": "StringUtil",
            "size": 4130
        }, {
            "name": "Sum",
            "size": 791
        }, {
            "name": "Variable",
            "size": 1124
        }, {
            "name": "Variance",
            "size": 1876
        }, {
            "name": "Xor",
            "size": 1101
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "scale",
        "children": [{
            "name": "IScaleMap",
            "size": 2105
        }, {
            "name": "LinearScale",
            "size": 1316
        }, {
            "name": "LogScale",
            "size": 3151
        }, {
            "name": "OrdinalScale",
            "size": 3770
        }, {
            "name": "QuantileScale",
            "size": 2435
        }, {
            "name": "QuantitativeScale",
            "size": 4839
        }, {
            "name": "dataScale",
            "size": 1756
        }, {
            "name": "Scale",
            "size": 4268
        }, {
            "name": "ScaleType",
            "size": 1821
        }, {
            "name": "TimeScale",
            "size": 5833
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "util",
        "children": [{
            "name": "Arrays",
            "size": 8258
        }, {
            "name": "Colors",
            "size": 10001
        }, {
            "name": "Dates",
            "size": 8217
        }, {
            "name": "Displays",
            "size": 12555
        }, {
            "name": "Filter",
            "size": 2324
        }, {
            "name": "Geometry",
            "size": 10993
        }, {
            "name": "heap",
            "children": [{
                "name": "FibonacciHeap",
                "size": 9354
            }, {
                "name": "HeapNode",
                "size": 1233
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "IEvaluable",
            "size": 335
        }, {
            "name": "IPredicate",
            "size": 383
        }, {
            "name": "IValueProxy",
            "size": 874
        }, {
            "name": "math",
            "children": [{
                "name": "DenseMatrix",
                "size": 3165
            }, {
                "name": "IMatrix",
                "size": 2815
            }, {
                "name": "SparseMatrix",
                "size": 3366
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Maths",
            "size": 17705
        }, {
            "name": "Orientation",
            "size": 1486
        }, {
            "name": "palette",
            "children": [{
                "name": "ColorPalette",
                "size": 6367
            }, {
                "name": "Palette",
                "size": 1229
            }, {
                "name": "ShapePalette",
                "size": 2059
            }, {
                "name": "SizePalette",
                "size": 2291
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Property",
            "size": 5559
        }, {
            "name": "Shapes",
            "size": 19118
        }, {
            "name": "Sort",
            "size": 6887
        }, {
            "name": "Stats",
            "size": 6557
        }, {
            "name": "Strings",
            "size": 22026
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "vis",
        "children": [{
            "name": "axis",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Axes",
                "size": 1302
            }, {
                "name": "Axis",
                "size": 24593
            }, {
                "name": "AxisGridLine",
                "size": 652
            }, {
                "name": "AxisLabel",
                "size": 636
            }, {
                "name": "CartesianAxes",
                "size": 6703
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "controls",
            "children": [{
                "name": "AnchorControl",
                "size": 2138
            }, {
                "name": "ClickControl",
                "size": 3824
            }, {
                "name": "Control",
                "size": 1353
            }, {
                "name": "ControlList",
                "size": 4665
            }, {
                "name": "DragControl",
                "size": 2649
            }, {
                "name": "ExpandControl",
                "size": 2832
            }, {
                "name": "HoverControl",
                "size": 4896
            }, {
                "name": "IControl",
                "size": 763
            }, {
                "name": "PanZoomControl",
                "size": 5222
            }, {
                "name": "SelectionControl",
                "size": 7862
            }, {
                "name": "TooltipControl",
                "size": 8435
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "data",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Data",
                "size": 20544
            }, {
                "name": "DataList",
                "size": 19788
            }, {
                "name": "DataSprite",
                "size": 10349
            }, {
                "name": "EdgeSprite",
                "size": 3301
            }, {
                "name": "NodeSprite",
                "size": 19382
            }, {
                "name": "render",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "ArrowType",
                    "size": 698
                }, {
                    "name": "EdgeRenderer",
                    "size": 5569
                }, {
                    "name": "IRenderer",
                    "size": 353
                }, {
                    "name": "ShapeRenderer",
                    "size": 2247
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "ScaleBinding",
                "size": 11275
            }, {
                "name": "Tree",
                "size": 7147
            }, {
                "name": "TreeBuilder",
                "size": 9930
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "events",
            "children": [{
                "name": "DataEvent",
                "size": 2313
            }, {
                "name": "SelectionEvent",
                "size": 1880
            }, {
                "name": "TooltipEvent",
                "size": 1701
            }, {
                "name": "VisualizationEvent",
                "size": 1117
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "legend",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Legend",
                "size": 20859
            }, {
                "name": "LegendItem",
                "size": 4614
            }, {
                "name": "LegendRange",
                "size": 10530
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "operator",
            "children": [{
                "name": "distortion",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "BifocalDistortion",
                    "size": 4461
                }, {
                    "name": "Distortion",
                    "size": 6314
                }, {
                    "name": "FisheyeDistortion",
                    "size": 3444
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "encoder",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "ColorEncoder",
                    "size": 3179
                }, {
                    "name": "Encoder",
                    "size": 4060
                }, {
                    "name": "PropertyEncoder",
                    "size": 4138
                }, {
                    "name": "ShapeEncoder",
                    "size": 1690
                }, {
                    "name": "SizeEncoder",
                    "size": 1830
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "filter",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "FisheyeTreeFilter",
                    "size": 5219
                }, {
                    "name": "GraphDistanceFilter",
                    "size": 3165
                }, {
                    "name": "VisibilityFilter",
                    "size": 3509
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "IOperator",
                "size": 1286
            }, {
                "name": "label",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Labeler",
                    "size": 9956
                }, {
                    "name": "RadialLabeler",
                    "size": 3899
                }, {
                    "name": "StackedAreaLabeler",
                    "size": 3202
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "layout",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "AxisLayout",
                    "size": 6725
                }, {
                    "name": "BundledEdgeRouter",
                    "size": 3727
                }, {
                    "name": "CircleLayout",
                    "size": 9317
                }, {
                    "name": "CirclePackingLayout",
                    "size": 12003
                }, {
                    "name": "DendrogramLayout",
                    "size": 4853
                }, {
                    "name": "ForceDirectedLayout",
                    "size": 8411
                }, {
                    "name": "IcicleTreeLayout",
                    "size": 4864
                }, {
                    "name": "IndentedTreeLayout",
                    "size": 3174
                }, {
                    "name": "Layout",
                    "size": 7881
                }, {
                    "name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout",
                    "size": 12870
                }, {
                    "name": "PieLayout",
                    "size": 2728
                }, {
                    "name": "RadialTreeLayout",
                    "size": 12348
                }, {
                    "name": "RandomLayout",
                    "size": 870
                }, {
                    "name": "StackedAreaLayout",
                    "size": 9121
                }, {
                    "name": "TreeMapLayout",
                    "size": 9191
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Operator",
                "size": 2490
            }, {
                "name": "OperatorList",
                "size": 5248
            }, {
                "name": "OperatorSequence",
                "size": 4190
            }, {
                "name": "OperatorSwitch",
                "size": 2581
            }, {
                "name": "SortOperator",
                "size": 2023
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Visualization",
            "size": 16540
        }]
    }]
}
function find(arr, condition){
  if(!arr) return null;
  for(let obj of arr) {
    if(condition(obj)) return obj
    let retVal = find(obj.children, condition)
    if(retVal) return retVal
  }
  return null
}
console.log(find(DATA.children, o => o.size ===  4461))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop recursively.

```js
let DATA = {    "name": "flare",    "children": [{        "name": "analytics",        "children": [{            "name": "cluster",            "children": [{                "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",                "size": 3938            }, {                "name": "CommunityStructure",                           "size": 3812            }, {                "name": "HierarchicalCluster",                "size": 6714            }, {                "name": "MergeEdge",                "size": 743            }]        }, {            "name": "graph",            "children": [{                "name": "BetweennessCentrality",                "size": 3534            }, {                "name": "LinkDistance",                "size": 5731            }, {                "name": "MaxFlowMinCut",                "size": 7840            }, {                "name": "ShortestPaths",                "size": 5914            }, {                "name": "SpanningTree",                "size": 3416            }]        }, {            "name": "optimization",            "children": [{                "name": "AspectRatioBanker",                "size": 7074            }]        }]    }, {        "name": "animate",        "children": [{            "name": "Easing",            "size": 17010        }, {            "name": "FunctionSequence",            "size": 5842        }, {            "name": "interpolate",            "children": [{                "name": "ArrayInterpolator",                "size": 1983            }, {                "name": "ColorInterpolator",                "size": 2047            }, {                "name": "DateInterpolator",                "size": 1375            }, {                "name": "Interpolator",                "size": 8746            }, {                "name": "MatrixInterpolator",                "size": 2202            }, {                "name": "NumberInterpolator",                "size": 1382            }, {                "name": "ObjectInterpolator",                "size": 1629            }, {                "name": "PointInterpolator",                "size": 1675            }, {                "name": "RectangleInterpolator",                "size": 2042            }]        }, {            "name": "ISchedulable",            "size": 1041        }, {            "name": "Parallel",            "size": 5176        }, {            "name": "Pause",            "size": 449        }, {            "name": "Scheduler",            "size": 5593        }, {            "name": "Sequence",            "size": 5534        }, {            "name": "Transition",            "size": 9201        }, {            "name": "Transitioner",            "size": 19975        }, {            "name": "TransitionEvent",            "size": 1116        }, {            "name": "Tween",            "size": 6006        }]    }, {        "name": "data",        "children": [{            "name": "converters",            "children": [{                "name": "Converters",                "size": 721            }, {                "name": "DelimitedTextConverter",                "size": 4294            }, {                "name": "GraphMLConverter",                "size": 9800            }, {                "name": "IDataConverter",                "size": 1314            }, {                "name": "JSONConverter",                "size": 2220            }]        }, {            "name": "DataField",            "size": 1759        }, {            "name": "DataSchema",            "size": 2165        }, {            "name": "DataSet",            "size": 586        }, {            "name": "DataSource",            "size": 3331        }, {            "name": "DataTable",            "size": 772        }, {            "name": "DataUtil",            "size": 3322        }]    }, {        "name": "display",        "children": [{            "name": "DirtySprite",            "size": 8833        }, {            "name": "LineSprite",            "size": 1732        }, {            "name": "RectSprite",            "size": 3623        }, {            "name": "TextSprite",            "size": 10066        }]    }, {        "name": "flex",        "children": [{            "name": "FlareVis",            "size": 4116        }]    }, {        "name": "physics",        "children": [{            "name": "DragForce",            "size": 1082        }, {            "name": "GravityForce",            "size": 1336        }, {            "name": "IForce",            "size": 319        }, {            "name": "NBodyForce",            "size": 10498        }, {            "name": "Particle",            "size": 2822        }, {            "name": "Simulation",            "size": 9983        }, {            "name": "Spring",            "size": 2213        }, {            "name": "SpringForce",            "size": 1681        }]    }, {        "name": "query",        "children": [{            "name": "AggregateExpression",            "size": 1616        }, {            "name": "And",            "size": 1027        }, {            "name": "Arithmetic",            "size": 3891        }, {            "name": "Average",            "size": 891        }, {            "name": "BinaryExpression",            "size": 2893        }, {            "name": "Comparison",            "size": 5103        }, {            "name": "CompositeExpression",            "size": 3677        }, {            "name": "Count",            "size": 781        }, {            "name": "DateUtil",            "size": 4141        }, {            "name": "Distinct",            "size": 933        }, {            "name": "Expression",            "size": 5130        }, {            "name": "ExpressionIterator",            "size": 3617        }, {            "name": "Fn",            "size": 3240        }, {            "name": "If",            "size": 2732        }, {            "name": "IsA",            "size": 2039        }, {            "name": "Literal",            "size": 1214        }, {            "name": "Match",            "size": 3748        }, {            "name": "Maximum",            "size": 843        }, {            "name": "methods",            "children": [{                "name": "add",                "size": 593            }, {                "name": "and",                "size": 330            }, {                "name": "average",                "size": 287            }, {                "name": "count",                "size": 277            }, {                "name": "distinct",                "size": 292            }, {                "name": "div",                "size": 595            }, {                "name": "eq",                "size": 594            }, {                "name": "fn",                "size": 460            }, {                "name": "gt",                "size": 603            }, {                "name": "gte",                "size": 625            }, {                "name": "iff",                "size": 748            }, {                "name": "isa",                "size": 461            }, {                "name": "lt",                "size": 597            }, {                "name": "lte",                "size": 619            }, {                "name": "max",                "size": 283            }, {                "name": "min",                "size": 283            }, {                "name": "mod",                "size": 591            }, {                "name": "mul",                "size": 603            }, {                "name": "neq",                "size": 599            }, {                "name": "not",                "size": 386            }, {                "name": "or",                "size": 323            }, {                "name": "orderby",                "size": 307            }, {                "name": "range",                "size": 772            }, {                "name": "select",                "size": 296            }, {                "name": "stddev",                "size": 363            }, {                "name": "sub",                "size": 600            }, {                "name": "sum",                "size": 280            }, {                "name": "update",                "size": 307            }, {                "name": "variance",                "size": 335            }, {                "name": "where",                "size": 299            }, {                "name": "xor",                "size": 354            }, {                "name": "_",                "size": 264            }]        }, {            "name": "Minimum",            "size": 843        }, {            "name": "Not",            "size": 1554        }, {            "name": "Or",            "size": 970        }, {            "name": "Query",            "size": 13896        }, {            "name": "Range",            "size": 1594        }, {            "name": "StringUtil",            "size": 4130        }, {            "name": "Sum",            "size": 791        }, {            "name": "Variable",            "size": 1124        }, {            "name": "Variance",            "size": 1876        }, {            "name": "Xor",            "size": 1101        }]    }, {        "name": "scale",        "children": [{            "name": "IScaleMap",            "size": 2105        }, {            "name": "LinearScale",            "size": 1316        }, {            "name": "LogScale",            "size": 3151        }, {            "name": "OrdinalScale",            "size": 3770        }, {            "name": "QuantileScale",            "size": 2435        }, {            "name": "QuantitativeScale",            "size": 4839        }, {            "name": "dataScale",            "size": 1756        }, {            "name": "Scale",            "size": 4268        }, {            "name": "ScaleType",            "size": 1821        }, {            "name": "TimeScale",            "size": 5833        }]    }, {        "name": "util",        "children": [{            "name": "Arrays",            "size": 8258        }, {            "name": "Colors",            "size": 10001        }, {            "name": "Dates",            "size": 8217        }, {            "name": "Displays",            "size": 12555        }, {            "name": "Filter",            "size": 2324        }, {            "name": "Geometry",            "size": 10993        }, {            "name": "heap",            "children": [{                "name": "FibonacciHeap",                "size": 9354            }, {                "name": "HeapNode",                "size": 1233            }]        }, {            "name": "IEvaluable",            "size": 335        }, {            "name": "IPredicate",            "size": 383        }, {            "name": "IValueProxy",            "size": 874        }, {            "name": "math",            "children": [{                "name": "DenseMatrix",                "size": 3165            }, {                "name": "IMatrix",                "size": 2815            }, {                "name": "SparseMatrix",                "size": 3366            }]        }, {            "name": "Maths",            "size": 17705        }, {            "name": "Orientation",            "size": 1486        }, {            "name": "palette",            "children": [{                "name": "ColorPalette",                "size": 6367            }, {                "name": "Palette",                "size": 1229            }, {                "name": "ShapePalette",                "size": 2059            }, {                "name": "SizePalette",                "size": 2291            }]        }, {            "name": "Property",            "size": 5559        }, {            "name": "Shapes",            "size": 19118        }, {            "name": "Sort",            "size": 6887        }, {            "name": "Stats",            "size": 6557        }, {            "name": "Strings",            "size": 22026        }]    }, {        "name": "vis",        "children": [{            "name": "axis",            "children": [{                "name": "Axes",                "size": 1302            }, {                "name": "Axis",                "size": 24593            }, {                "name": "AxisGridLine",                "size": 652            }, {                "name": "AxisLabel",                "size": 636            }, {                "name": "CartesianAxes",                "size": 6703            }]        }, {            "name": "controls",            "children": [{                "name": "AnchorControl",                "size": 2138            }, {                "name": "ClickControl",                "size": 3824            }, {                "name": "Control",                "size": 1353            }, {                "name": "ControlList",                "size": 4665            }, {                "name": "DragControl",                "size": 2649            }, {                "name": "ExpandControl",                "size": 2832            }, {                "name": "HoverControl",                "size": 4896            }, {                "name": "IControl",                "size": 763            }, {                "name": "PanZoomControl",                "size": 5222            }, {                "name": "SelectionControl",                "size": 7862            }, {                "name": "TooltipControl",                "size": 8435            }]        }, {            "name": "data",            "children": [{                "name": "Data",                "size": 20544            }, {                "name": "DataList",                "size": 19788            }, {                "name": "DataSprite",                "size": 10349            }, {                "name": "EdgeSprite",                "size": 3301            }, {                "name": "NodeSprite",                "size": 19382            }, {                "name": "render",                "children": [{                    "name": "ArrowType",                    "size": 698                }, {                    "name": "EdgeRenderer",                    "size": 5569                }, {                    "name": "IRenderer",                    "size": 353                }, {                    "name": "ShapeRenderer",                    "size": 2247                }]            }, {                "name": "ScaleBinding",                "size": 11275            }, {                "name": "Tree",                "size": 7147            }, {                "name": "TreeBuilder",                "size": 9930            }]        }, {            "name": "events",            "children": [{                "name": "DataEvent",                "size": 2313            }, {                "name": "SelectionEvent",                "size": 1880            }, {                "name": "TooltipEvent",                "size": 1701            }, {                "name": "VisualizationEvent",                "size": 1117            }]        }, {            "name": "legend",            "children": [{                "name": "Legend",                "size": 20859            }, {                "name": "LegendItem",                "size": 4614            }, {                "name": "LegendRange",                "size": 10530            }]        }, {            "name": "operator",            "children": [{                "name": "distortion",                "children": [{                    "name": "BifocalDistortion",                    "size": 4461                }, {                    "name": "Distortion",                    "size": 6314                }, {                    "name": "FisheyeDistortion",                    "size": 3444                }]            }, {                "name": "encoder",                "children": [{                    "name": "ColorEncoder",                    "size": 3179                }, {                    "name": "Encoder",                    "size": 4060                }, {                    "name": "PropertyEncoder",                    "size": 4138                }, {                    "name": "ShapeEncoder",                    "size": 1690                }, {                    "name": "SizeEncoder",                    "size": 1830                }]            }, {                "name": "filter",                "children": [{                    "name": "FisheyeTreeFilter",                    "size": 5219                }, {                    "name": "GraphDistanceFilter",                    "size": 3165                }, {                    "name": "VisibilityFilter",                    "size": 3509                }]            }, {                "name": "IOperator",                "size": 1286            }, {                "name": "label",                "children": [{                    "name": "Labeler",                    "size": 9956                }, {                    "name": "RadialLabeler",                    "size": 3899                }, {                    "name": "StackedAreaLabeler",                    "size": 3202                }]            }, {                "name": "layout",                "children": [{                    "name": "AxisLayout",                    "size": 6725                }, {                    "name": "BundledEdgeRouter",                    "size": 3727                }, {                    "name": "CircleLayout",                    "size": 9317                }, {                    "name": "CirclePackingLayout",                    "size": 12003                }, {                    "name": "DendrogramLayout",                    "size": 4853                }, {                    "name": "ForceDirectedLayout",                    "size": 8411                }, {                    "name": "IcicleTreeLayout",                    "size": 4864                }, {                    "name": "IndentedTreeLayout",                    "size": 3174                }, {                    "name": "Layout",                    "size": 7881                }, {                    "name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout",                    "size": 12870                }, {                    "name": "PieLayout",                    "size": 2728                }, {                    "name": "RadialTreeLayout",                    "size": 12348                }, {                    "name": "RandomLayout",                    "size": 870                }, {                    "name": "StackedAreaLayout",                    "size": 9121                }, {                    "name": "TreeMapLayout",                    "size": 9191                }]            }, {                "name": "Operator",                "size": 2490            }, {                "name": "OperatorList",                "size": 5248            }, {                "name": "OperatorSequence",                "size": 4190            }, {                "name": "OperatorSwitch",                "size": 2581            }, {                "name": "SortOperator",                "size": 2023            }]        }, {            "name": "Visualization",            "size": 16540        }]    }]}


function loop(obj) {
  if (obj.children) {
    for (var c of obj.children) {
      if (c.size === 4461) return c;
      else {
        var found = loop(c);
        if (found) return found;
      }
    }
  }
}

var result = loop(DATA);
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Care to comment for that downvote :-)